# How does the author convey the tone of the panic that can be aroused by contemplating the "prenatal abyss"?

Tags: short-stories, vladimir-nabokov

In the text of Vladimir Nabokov: The Beginning of Consciousness

How does the author convey the tone of the panic that can be aroused by contemplating the "prenatal abyss"?

> The cradle rocks above an abyss, and common sense tells us that our
>   existence is but a brief crack of light between two eternities of
>   darkness. Although the two are identical twins, man, as a rule, views
>   the prenatal abyss with more calm than the one he is headed for (at
>   some forty-five hundred heartbeats an hour). I know, however, of a
>   young chronophobiac who experienced something like panic when looking
>   for the first time at homemade movies that had been taken a few weeks
>   before his birth. He saw a world that was practically unchanged — the
>   same house, the same people — and then realized that he did not exist
>   there at all and that nobody mourned his absence. He caught a glimpse
>   of his mother waving from an upstairs window, and that unfamiliar
>   gesture disturbed him, as if it were some mysterious farewell. But
>   what particularly frightened him was the sight of a brand-new baby
>   carriage standing there on the porch; even that was empty, as if, in
>   the reverse order of events, his very bones had disintegrated. Such
>   fancies are not foreign to young lives. Or, to put it otherwise, first
>   and last things often tend to have an adolescent note — unless,
>   possibly, they are directed by some venerable and rigid religion.
>   Nature expects a full-grown man to accept the two black voids, fore
>   and aft, as stolidly as he accepts the extraordinary visions in
>   between. Imagination, the supreme delight of the immortal and
>   immature, should be limited. In order to enjoy life, we should not
>   enjoy it too much. I rebel against this state of affairs. I feel the
>   urge to take my rebellion outside and picket nature. Over and over
>   again, my mind has made colossal efforts to distinguish the faintest
>   of personal glimmers in the impersonal darkness on both sides of my
>   life. That this darkness is caused merely by the walls of time
>   separating me and my bruised fists from the free world of timelessness
>   is a belief I gladly share with the most gaudily painted savage. I
>   have journeyed back in thought — with thought hopelessly tapering off
>   as I went — to remote regions where I groped for some secret outlet
>   only to discover that the prison of time is spherical and without
>   exits. Short of suicide, I have tried everything. I have doffed my
>   identity in order to pass for a conventional spook and steal into
>   realms that existed before I was conceived. I have mentally endured
>   the degrading company of Victorian lady novelists and retired colonels
>   who remembered having, in former lives, been slave messengers on a
>   Roman road or sages under the willows of Lhasa. I have ransacked my
>   oldest dreams for keys and clues — and let me say at once that I
>   reject completely the vulgar, shabby, fundamentally medieval world of
>   Freud, with its crankish quest for sexual symbols (something like
>   searching for Baconian acrostics in Shakespeare’s works) and its
>   bitter little embryos spying, from their natural nooks, upon the love
>   life of their parents. Initially, I was unaware that time, so
>   boundless at first blush, was a prison. In probing my childhood (which
>   is the next best to probing one’s eternity) I see the awakening of
>   consciousness as a series of spaced flashes, with the intervals
>   between them gradually diminishing until bright blocks of perception
>   are formed, affording memory a slippery hold. I had learned numbers
>   and speech more or less simultaneously at a very early date, but the
>   inner knowledge that I was I and that my parents were my parents seems
>   to have been established only later, when it was directly associated
>   with my discovering their age in relation to mine. Judging by the
>   strong sunlight that, when I think of that revelation, immediately
>   invades my memory with lobed sun flecks through overlapping patterns
>   of greenery, the occasion may have been my mother’s birthday, in late
>   summer, in the country, and I had asked questions and had assessed the
>   answers I received. All this is as it should be according to the
>   theory of recapitulation; the beginning of reflexive consciousness in
>   the brain of our remotest ancestor must surely have coincided with the
>   dawning of the sense of time. Thus, when the newly disclosed, fresh
>   and trim formula of my own age, four, was confronted with the parental
>   formulas, thirty-three and twenty-seven, something happened to me. I
>   was given a tremendously invigorating shock. As if subjected to a
>   second baptism, on more divine lines than the Greek Catholic ducking
>   undergone fifty months earlier by a howling, half-drowned half-Victor
>   (my mother, through the half-closed door, behind which an old custom
>   bade parents retreat, managed to correct the bungling archpresbyter,
>   Father Konstantin Vetvenitski), I felt myself plunged abruptly into a
>   radiant and mobile medium that was none other than the pure element of
>   time. One shared it — just as excited bathers share shining seawater —
>   with creatures that were not oneself but that were joined to one by
>   time’s common flow, an environment quite different from the spacial
>   world, which not only man but apes and butterflies can perceive. At
>   that instant, I became acutely aware that the twenty-seven-year-old
>   being, in soft white and pink, holding my left hand, was my mother,
>   and that the thirty-three-year-old being, in hard white and gold,
>   holding my right hand, was my father. Between them, as they evenly
>   progressed, I strutted, and trotted, and strutted again, from sun
>   fleck to sun fleck, along the middle of the path, which I easily
>   identify today with an alley of ornamental oaklings in the park of our
>   country estate, Vyra, in the former Province of St. Petersburg,
>   Russia. Indeed, from my present ridge of remote, isolated, almost
>   uninhabited time, I see my diminutive self as celebrating, on that
>   August day 1903, the birth of sentient life. If my left-hand-holder
>   and my right-hand-holder had both been present before in my vague
>   infant world, they had been so under the mask of a tender incognito;
>   but now my father’s attire, the resplendent uniform of the House
>   Guards, with that smooth golden swell of cuirass burning upon his
>   chest and back, came out like the sun, and for several years afterward
>   I remained keenly interested in the age of my parents and kept myself
>   informed about it, like a nervous passenger asking the time in order
>   to check a new watch. My father, let it be noted, had served his term
>   of military training long before I was born, so I suppose he had that
>   day put on the trappings of his old regiment as a festive joke. To a
>   joke, then, I owe my first gleam of complete consciousness — which
>   again has recapitulatory implications, since the first creatures on
>   earth to become aware of time were also the first creatures to smile.